# Full screen ContainerViewController

Tags: ios, uicontainerview, childviewcontroller

I wish to add a childViewController that will be presented full screen.
Is that possible without hiding the navigation bar ?

Thanks

Comment: can u provide a sketch ? why would you not hide the nav bar ?

Comment: Since the childViewController is a countdown controller and the user can not interact with it while count down is running + Design requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your own view the navigation bar, if it is embedded with the following code:

**Swift way:**
*To hide it:*

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

*To show it:*

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

**Objective-C way:**
*Hide:*

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

*Show:*

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Comment: hope this answer helps you, if you need more information how to embed the navigation, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks but I stated in the question that I do not want to hide the navigation bar